# AH00015: Unable to open logs Action 'start' failed. in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache2

I am trying install apache2,i faced this problem.Give me some solutions

Restarting web server apache2 gives the error:

```
    AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
[fail]
 * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
```

Comment: Could you post your apache configuration file?

Comment: sorry,how to get the apache configuration file?

Comment: It should be `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` and if you have defined your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/yourFile.conf`

Answer (score 12):

Run

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
```

and you will get output something like

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80         0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN     1066/lighttpd
```

note the pid of the process listening to the port, in my case it was 1066. Then run

```
sudo kill -9 1066
```

**Remember to change the pid to the one that is listening to the port, It might not be the same as 1066**

Answer (score 2):

What type of server are you running this on?

To resolve the first error

> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

You will need to edit `httpd.conf` file, add this line:

```
ServerName localhost
```

To resolve the other errors you should make sure that you are trying to run Apache with root privileges.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl start
```

Comment: This wasn't their real error.

Comment: I don't have a `httpd.conf` file. Can I put that line into `apache2.conf`?

Comment: Setting `ServerName` in `httpd.conf` has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Like many server applications, you can't bind to a port already bound to by another application (in this case, port 80, for `http`).  The cause of your error is that Apache can't bind to port 80 because something else is already listening there.

Run `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80` and look for the name of the process that's listening on port 80.  Then, either reconfigure or remove that program.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same problem.

I tried to install LAMP on WSL by following this blog: [LAMP on WSL](https://medium.com/@ssharizal/how-to-install-lamp-stack-server-on-windows-subsystem-linux-wsl-windows-10-133419c22473) but when I  issued this command :

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

I got this same error:

```
 * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2                                                                             
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
*
```

I had previously tried to install Nginx on Windows proper and failed but I remembered I  had bound Nginx to port 80. Problem is I am no Linux expert and I could not see in apache2 conf file the area to bind to a port.

I tried running:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
```

and got nothing. I had also forwarded the port in my router so I could not understand how to solve the error.

I know Nginx was not running so port 80 should have been fine except for chrome which I assume was also running on port 80
So in frustration not knowing what will happen I proceeded the command with `sudo` like this:

```
sudo  /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

and I got:

```
 * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2                                                                              
 *
```

By proceeding the start command with `sudo`, Apache2 has authority to run. This is a short-term solution because it is not advisable to run Apache2 with root privileges (so we are informed) so the solution is still out there but for now, I can at least proceed with my tests.

If anyone knows the solution do please let us know.

Comment: @Yufenyuy thanks. I tried to catch all the codes but ...

Comment: ...@seanbw you're welcome. That's why we're in a community...

Comment: @Yufenyuy The edits I get. Most. can you give me a link that teaches me how to tag words like sudo as part of a sentence because I see that sudo has its own format but its not on a separate line. Thanks

Comment: ...@seanbw you can enclose the word between ` and ` example `sudo`, for it to have that format... hope you get it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You may installed a new web server or anything reserve the port 80
check your services and what you have newly installed

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was not a problem with logs, but actually with the `Listen` directive - it was set to Listen on an IP that did not exists (as I moved my laptop to another network).

This only surfaced after I uninstalled the service, reinstalled it and it said:

`(OS 10049) The requested address is not valid in its context.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
AH00015: Unable to open logs`

So I just commented out the offending Listen directive (and kept others) an voila.

I know the Q is about Ubuntu, but some other people might land here encountering the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a ssl.conf which was under the conf.d directory which was causing the problem. If you have defined the Listen flag on your main httpd.conf file, you can rename the ssl.conf file to something

Answer (score 0):

Tried https://askubuntu.com/a/923992/698546

But the program kept creating new processes as I killed an old one.

A simple **restart** of the server did the trick for me.