# Reinstalling Apache fails, 'could not bind to address' error

Tags: apache2

I tried to reinstall Apache web server, but I got the following error message:

```
 * Starting web server apache2                                                  AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 * 
 * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
```

Anyone have same experience and knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Action 'start' failed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/500977/ah00015-unable-to-open-logs-action-start-failed-in-ubuntu-14-04) ?

Answer (score 0):

Like many server applications, you can't bind to a port already bound to by another application.  The cause of your error is that Apache can't bind to port 80 because something else is already listening there.

Run `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80` and look for the name of the process that's listening on port 80.  Then, either reconfigure or remove that program.  (If you provide the output for us in an edit to your question we can try and help you further).

Comment: so what is the command to reconfigure or remove the program or process listening on port 80

Comment: @user1 It depends on what's listening on that port, are you going to run the command and provide the output so we can help debug it further?  (Provide the output as an EDIT to your question)

Comment: ooh thanks but i fought with it and finally managed to debug it ,the command was to kill the process eg kill 80 .But thanks for your advise